# Returning error status from GCP python cloud function (not 'ok' or 'crash')

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, error-handling, google-cloud-functions, python-3.7

I would like to distinguish between 3 cases when triggering my Python Cloud Function from Pub/Sub: 'ok', 'error' (for example invalid data) or 'crash'.

But I cannot find a way of doing anything except status 'ok' or status 'crash' so far.

A couple of pages suggest various things, for example:

https://googleapis.dev/python/clouderrorreporting/latest/usage.html#reporting-an-error-without-an-exception suggests using `client.report()`, but this gives the same status as `client_exception()` - 'crash'.

Likewise, the official page https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/error-reporting has several methods, but when they write "error", in reality the status in the logs is 'crash'.

Is this possible? Thank you.

Comment: What do you want to happen in the "error" and "crash" states? Should the Pub/Sub message be retried?

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Functions indeed have 3 different "final states", Ok, which ends with a 200 and return your output, crash, when the function has a bug or encounter an error that is not capable of handling and retry.

If you want to action on a third "error" status you can implement a retry to make your function capable of solving some transient errors.

In order to do so you should include the --retry flag when deploying your function.

Here is the [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/retries) explaining the best practices to implement retry into your Cloud Functions.

Now if you are just concern about your log status you should keep in mind that Stackdriver Logging severity filters are no supported when using the Python native logging module.

However, you can still create logs with a certain severity by using the [Stackdriver Logging Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries).

Notice that in order to let the logs be under the correct resource, you will have to manually configure them, see [this list](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/v2/resource-list#resource-indexes) for the supported resource types. 
As well, each resource type has some [required labels](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/v2/resource-list#resource-types) that need to be present in the log structure.

Here you can find a sample that will report an `ERROR`

```
from google.cloud import logging
from google.cloud.logging.resource import Resource

log_client = logging.Client()

# This is the resource type of the log
log_name = 'cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions' 

# Inside the resource, nest the required labels specific to the resource type
res = Resource(type="cloud_function", 
               labels={
                   "function_name": "YOUR-CLOUD-FUNCTION-NAME", 
                   "region": "YOUR-FUNCTION-LOCATION"
               },
              )
logger = log_client.logger(log_name.format("YOUR-PROJECT-ID"))
logger.log_struct(
 {"message": "message string to log"}, resource=res, severity='ERROR')

return 'Wrote logs to {}.'.format(logger.name) # Return cloud function response
```